# How to store string into an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a variable that will receive foldernames and I would like to store those names into an array. here is the array declaration and piece of code that will hopefully do what i would want. the variable fold is the variable contaiing the filename.

```
trainingLabels = zeros(315,1);
testingLabels = zeros(336,1);
if folder == 1
            test(:,:,:,testctr) = Image;
            testingLabels(testctr,1) = {fold};
            testctr = testctr+1;
        else
            train(:,:,:,trainctr) = Image;
            trainingLabels(trainctr,1) = {fold};
            trainctr = trainctr+1;
        end
```

Comment: Store them in a cell array instead. testingLabels = cell{315,1}

Comment: @JakobL I tried that but this piece of code will be used for loading testing and training images and labels for sample code of object detection in mathworks [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-using-deep-learning.html) and its giving me an error "Invalid training data. Y must be a vector of categorical responses." where Y is the trainingLabels.